# Using Google ReCaptcha v3 in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recaptcha-v3

Using React ^16.13.1 & Next ^9.4.4

Attempting to get [react-google-recaptcha-v3](https://github.com/t49tran/react-google-recaptcha-v3) working within my app.

It appears to be hanging at `const result = await executeRecaptcha("homepage")` in `pages/index.js`.

`console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY)` returns correct key.

Hard coding the key in `pages/_app.js` throws some errors in browser:

`` A cookie associated with a resource at http://google.com/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032. ``

`` A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://www.google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032. ``

```
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:6
_throw @ asyncToGenerator.js:29
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
clickHandler @ index.js:34
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:306
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:389
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:414
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:3278
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3287
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:3259
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3304
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3514
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3558
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21871
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:795
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:3568
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4267
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4189
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21887
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:806
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4168
```

`pages/_app.js`

```
import { GoogleReCaptchaProvider } from 'react-google-recaptcha-v3';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <GoogleReCaptchaProvider
            reCaptchaKey={process.env.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}
        >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

`pages/index.js`

```
import { useGoogleReCaptcha } from 'react-google-recaptcha-v3'

const index = () => {
    const [token, setToken] = React.useState("");
    const { executeRecaptcha } = useGoogleReCaptcha()
    const clickHandler = async () => {
        if (!executeRecaptcha) {
            return;
        }

        const result = await executeRecaptcha("homepage");

        setToken(result);
        console.log(token)
    };
    return (
        <Button type='submit' color='blue' onClick={clickHandler}>Test GRecap</Button>
    )
}

export default index
```

Comment: What did you end up doing with `result`? Shouldn't you use this to verify the actions of the user somehow?

Answer (score 14):

Two issues with my code:

The react-google-recaptcha-v3 package was hanging due to the way [next.js handles .env variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables). To expose the .env variable to the browser you need to prefix it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Testing locally with google recaptcha v3 you need to create a new key to use for dev using localhost as domain.